# paypal ipn max time for incomplete transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I am integrating paypal (for the first time) in a website using PHP. From what I have read, there are two methods for confirming a successful transaction, PDT and IPN.

Now the thing is, the item's being sold can have a limited stock. So if suppose a person reserves an item and is taken to the PAYPAL site for final payment, I have to stop all other people from making a purchase since the last piece of the item will be "reserved".

But suppose the person (who has reserved the final piece of the item) goes to the paypal page, and then simply closes it. Will this result in a "fail" ipn coming to me (so I should un-reserve the item so others can buy)?

If so, how long will it take for the failed IPN to come?

If not, how exactly should I handle this.

And is there any scenario where an IPN does not come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Express Checkout API.
With EC, the payment is a two step process. In the first step, you make an API call (SetExpressCheckout) where you set up the transaction, and redirect the buyer to PayPal. Once there, the buyer authorizes the payment, and returns to your site.

At this point no money has changed hands. You need to make a second API call in order to capture the funds (DoExpressCheckout).

You can hold the item for a specific period, and if the buyer abandons the transaction, or is very slow to approve the payment, you can release the item back to the public.  If he eventually approves it, and does come back to your site, you would simply skip the second step, and inform the user that his transaction timed out.  No money changes hands, no items are double sold.

Comment: thanks man..really wish you would have answered earlier though since I have already implemented most of the solution now using IPN+PDT method :(....